# Why is my boundingRectWithSize not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
stringSize = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200,300) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:self.stringLabel.font.fontName size:self.stringLabel.font.pointSize]} context:nil];
```

The original code was

```
 stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:self.stringLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 300)];
```

But Apple's Xcode said it was deprecated so I wanted to update it and now I'm having issues with the first parameter.

I get an error that says the following

```
SVProgressHUD.m:298:28: Assigning to 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize') from incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect')
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Is the height it returns incorrect?

Comment: Your returned value is `CGRect` which you are trying to assign it to a `CGSize` hence the error. `CGRect` has a member named `size` which is of  type `CGSize` that you want to use here.

Answer (score 1):

As Desdenova says.

You could do:

```
CGRect stringRect = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200,300) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:self.stringLabel.font.fontName size:self.stringLabel.font.pointSize]} context:nil];
```

You could also go with:

```
CGSize stringSize = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200,300) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:nil context:nil].size;
```